# struts comes under which layer of three tier architecture in real time projects

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

Where do struts come under in three tier architecture in real time projects? Please I need explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts is an entire framework and isn't really going to only be one layer of the typical "three tier" architecture (presentation, application, and data storage).

Struts is going to provide you an MVC framework in Java land. You'll be able to better divide your presentation layer, application layer, and data persistance rather than mingle and mash them all together.

Answer (score 2):

what is three tire architechture?

In 3-tier, the application logic (or) process lives in the 
middle-tier, it is separated from the data and the user 
interface. 3-tier systems are more scalable, robust and 
flexible. In addition, they can integrate data from 
multiple sources. In the three tier architecture, a middle 
tier was added between the user system interface client 
environment and the database management server environment. 
There are a variety of ways of implementing this middle 
tier, such as transaction processing monitors, message 
servers, or application servers. The middle tier can 
perform queuing, application execution, and database 
staging. For example, if the middle tier provides queuing, 
the client can deliver its request to the middle layer and 
disengage because the middle tier will access the data and 
return the answer to the client
The most basic type of three tier architecture has a middle 
layer consisting of Transaction Processing (TP) monitor 
technology. The TP monitor technology is a type of message 
queuing, transaction scheduling, and prioritization service 
where the client connects to the TP monitor (middle tier) 
instead of the database server. The transaction is accepted 
by the monitor, which queues it and then takes 
responsibility for managing it to completion, thus freeing 
up the client.

Answer (score 1):

Wrt the architecture of application projects struts is the framework which is generally used for the presentation layer with jsp and servlets being the technologies in the same. Coming to the service layer, EJB is the technology and Spring is the framework and in data access layer, JDBC and JPA are the technologies with Hibernate being the framework.